# Can we match a parent node using it's child element name?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to match the parent node using it's child element name.
Example:

```
<parent><child1>text</child1></parent>
```

Here i want to match parent element but i don't know the parent tag name but what i know is it's child element name. So i need to perform tranformation on parent tag and that's why i need to match the parent tag using it's child element name .And also if parent of child tag is root then i don't want to perform any transformation.

For more clearity i need to match something like `<xsl:template match="[ancestor::contentblock]"> or <xsl:template match="[parent::contentblock]">` but xslt doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```xml
//*/*[child1]
```

If the xpath is used in an xsl:template match, you can leave off the `//`.

```xml
match="*/*[child1]"
```

**Edit**

This should be more of what you're looking for:

```xml
match="*[parent::*][.//child1]"
```

This matches any element that has a parent element and also a descendant `child1` element.

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dVG

Comment: Haley thanks for the solution but it works only when there is one level of parenting like <parent><child1>text</child1></parent> but not work when there are multiple levels like <parent1><parent2><child1>text</child1></parent2></parent1>. And in this case also i know the name child1 and want to transform both parent1 and parent2. FYI I just want to remove all parents except root for this child tag.

Comment: It helps if you use the correct terminology. You seem to be using the word "parent" where you mean "ancestor": that pretty well ensures that people will misunderstand your question.

Comment: Note also, your last paragraph: it doesn't add any clarity to explain your requirement using syntax that isn't defined in XSLT or anywhere else.

Comment: @rajatsethi - Please see my edit. Hopefully that's more of what you're looking for. Like Dr. Kay said, the "parent" terminology threw me off.

Comment: @MichaelKay Daniel Haley I'm sorry if that terminology confuses the others. I'll try to be more clear and direct for my future question. I'm a new bee in this xslt world.